# How to resolve the SqlException: ResultSet is from UPDATE,No Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey

> Hibernate operation: could not execute query; SQL [call sp_getNearbyTags (?,?,?,?,?)]; ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exceptionorg.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; SQL [call sp_getNearbyTags (?,?,?,?,?)]; ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
>           org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)
>           org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>           org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>           org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
>           org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
>           org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
>           org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:412)
>           org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
>           com.thingovation.smartcollar.dao.PublicApiDAOImpl.fetchDogsNearBy(PublicApiDAOImpl.java:125)
>           com.thingovation.smartcollar.controller.PublicApiRestController.fetchDogsNearBy(PublicApiRestController.java:252)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Can ypu please provide me with HibernateTemplate?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please suggest to me I am not able find out the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code causing the problem?

Comment: I resolved the problem by clean up the Work Space in Eclipse          Thanks\